Saving and dropping a dataframe in a for loop
I have a number of dataframes from which I have to take a sample. The samples taken from that dataframe, have to be excluded from the next dataframe in order to not have any 'double' samples as there is some overlap.
my code is as follows
df_list = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5]
samplesizes = [8, 2, 4, 4, 2]

sample = []

for df, samplesize in zip(df_list, samplesizes):
    if sample: #can't drop in the first loop
        df = df.drop(sample) #I want to drop the taken samples from the current df

    if max_pop_size < len(df):
        samplesize = max_pop_size #can't take a sample larger than population

    sample.append(df.sample(samplesize, random_state=1000))



I get stuck on the dropping after the first loop. I've tried several things and none seem to work.
EDIT: the df's are a subset of 1 big population, so the columns are identical. the subsets (in df_list) are sliced based on earlier criteria which may contain duplicates. If a sample is taken, we don't want that specific row to be in the population of the next sample. To make things easier, they all have the same index!
Any help would be much appreciated!

why dont you drop the duplicates after appending all samples?

Do you need to exclude them before or after sampling? Can you provide an [mre] of the DataFrames?

@BendingRodriguez because I need to take the maximum amount of samples. If i drop duplicates after appending, that leaves me with less samples than needed

@mozway before sampling, so earlier samples should not be in the population of the next sampling

then if you need 1000 samples, why dont you take like 1500 first, then drop duplicates and then pick 1000 random samples?

@BendingRodriguez a lot of times, the population is smaller than the samplesize so that would not work

@borisvanax what does that mean? you mean in the sets alone or in the sum off all sets?

Just to be sure: df1, df2,... are different dataframes with same columns but may contain the same data rows? Or are they the same dataframe, and you want to simulate drawing without replacement?

this needs some details and clarity to me

This is an interesting and not straightforward problem.
I think you cannot/shouldn't:

pre-filter the duplicates, since it might remove too many rows (it might remove a row in group 2 that was in group 1 even if it was not sampled from group 1)
sample then post-filter, since removing rows after sampling would decrease the sample size in an unpredictable way
concatenate the sampled DataFrames in the loop(*), this has quadratic complexity and would make the code slow for a large number of inputs

I think a reasonable approach could be to first compute an ID to identify duplicated rows, then to loop over the groups and keep track of the already sampled rows:
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [10,20,30]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2,3,4], 'B': [20,30,40]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,4,5], 'B': [10,40,50]})
np.random.seed(1)

df_list = [df1, df2, df3]
samplesizes = [2, 1, 1]

# combine all datasets to be able to identify the duplicates
tmp = (pd.concat(df_list, keys=range(len(df_list)))
         .assign(ID=lambda d: d.groupby(list(tmp)).ngroup())
         .set_index('ID', append=True)
      )

# set to keep track of already sampled unique IDs
seen = set()

# for each input (group)
# first remove the already sampled rows
# then sample the expected size
sample = []
for k, g in tmp.groupby(level=0, sort=False):
    selected = g.drop(index=seen, level='ID').sample(samplesizes[k])
    seen.update(selected.index.get_level_values('ID'))
    sample.append(selected.droplevel([0, -1]))

print(sample)

Of course, it could be that in some cases there are not enough rows left to sample from, but this is not really avoidable if you want to maintain an unbiased sampling.
Example output:
[   A   B
 0  1  10
 2  3  30,
    A   B
 2  4  40,
    A   B
 2  5  50]

(*) concatenating in a loop
If your have a small number of DataFrames and rows, concatenating in a loop the total sampled rows (concat+merge) might be acceptable. This gives a shorter code:
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [10,20,30]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2,3,4], 'B': [20,30,40]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,4,5], 'B': [10,40,50]})
np.random.seed(1)

df_list = [df1, df2, df3]
samplesizes = [2, 1, 1]

sample = []
total = pd.DataFrame(columns=df_list[0].columns)
for df, samplesize in zip(df_list, samplesizes):
    selected = (df.merge(total, how='left', indicator=True)
                  .loc[lambda x: x.pop('_merge').eq('left_only')]
                  .sample(samplesize)
               )
    total = pd.concat([total, selected])
    sample.append(selected)

print(sample)

Example output:
[   A   B
0  1  10
2  3  30,
    A   B
2  4  40,
    A   B
2  5  50]


your third point should not be a problem, there's only a max of 10 dataframes with only hundreds of rows each. Also, all the df in the df_list have the same index. so excluding based on index is a possibility. does that make it any easier?

I don't know, I'll try. I just saw your edit, which suggests that you don't even need to split the original big DataFrame in the first place.

no the slicing can happen in the for loop, but then i would need to loop over a specified mask or something. would not really matter for the result I guess

See update for a concat+merge-based approach

concat+merge does the trick for me! thanks :)

@borisvanax would you mind providing a feedback on the timings with your real life datasets for the two options? (feel free to [edit] my answer)
